# how to publish my jsp project on internet using tomcat,mysql and jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I have completed my semester project using jsp,tomcat server,mysql database and jdbc driver.I dont have any idea how to publish it on internet.It is working fine in localhost.Please help.

Comment: you want the application to be accessed using a domain or through your local infrastructure?

Comment: i want the application to be accessed using domain.If i type www.myprojectname.com as url in any browser i wish to see the home page of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to purchase a domain and a hosting place. Your hoster should support Tomcat and MySQL service. Then you need to build up your database, and deploy your application on the Tomcat server. And voila!

Note: The jdbc driver is not an issue since it can be included within your application...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Can you please suggest free domain and hosting place.I just want to test it as if it works on the internet.Actually iam new to this.

Comment: i dont know about free ones, there are paid ones with 2-3 dollars per month

Comment: @leela if an answer helps you you can upvote it and accept it